# Radio group not working if selected radio button is selected

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, radio-group

I am populating a radiogroup with some radiobuttons progmatically
My code:

```
cats.forEach {
            val radioButton = RadioButton(requireContext()).apply {
                tag = map[it]
                text = "%d %s".format(map[it],it)
                isChecked = map[it] == selectedCeVo
            }
            Timber.i("cat: data ${map[it]} data1 $selectedCeVo")
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton)
        }
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
            val radioButton = binding.root.findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId)
            ce.value = radioButton.tag as Long
            Timber.i("cat: ce value ${ce.value}")
            listener.invoke(ce)
            dismiss()
        }

    }
```

When I check the selected radio button this works but does not work for a preselected radio button. What am I missing please help,.

Comment: Each of the `RadioButton`s needs a unique ID. There's a handy function in `View` you could use: `id = View.generateViewId()`.

Comment: alright ! Let me try it out.

Comment: @MikeM. it did not work. What could be the issue ?

Comment: it is working perfectly if I keep making new selections

Comment: I guess I don't understand what the specific issue is, then. You definitely want to keep the unique IDs on the `RadioButton`s, though.

Comment: ok Mike thanks for trying.

Comment: hii I set the click listeners on the radio button itself and it's working.... still not sure about the reason behind this weird behaviour